# Rudimentary RSA Encryption Implementation issue

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, greatest-common-divisor

I'm having issues with a basic RSA Encryption implementation for one of my classes. I've spent several hours on this one issue and can't seem to make any progress hunting down the culprit.

p and q remain the same and are not required to change for the assignment. I've confirmed my code outputs the same p and q every time and both are prime.

During the test I've made, I receive some successes and some failures, and I can't differentiate what is causing the failures.

I have verified that the key pairs are always generated in the same format, just with a different e and d.

I've verified that the extended Euclidean algorithm always generates the correct value for d by manually plugging the numbers into the following website calculator: https://www.dcode.fr/extended-gcd.

In addition, I've made sure it is calculating **e*d = 1 (mod phi(n))** and not **e*d = 1 (mod n)**

Valid messages are fed to the encryption algorithm (1 < msg < n)

I've used https://www.wolframalpha.com to verify that the encryption and decryption via python's pow() function are also working.

There are checks to make sure that an appropriate value of e was selected, and it appears valid e's are being selected by the program.

1 < e < phi(n),
e is co-prime with n and phi(n),
are there other constraints on selecting e?

The full codebase can be found here https://github.com/nicksettoon/RSA-SHA256_4562.

test function:

```
    START = 1000
    LIMIT = 10000
    pthPrime = 10
    qthPrime = 19
    keytests = 25
    msgtests = 10
    p,q = getPrimes(START, LIMIT, pthPrime, qthPrime)

    for i in range(1, keytests+1):
        print(f"\nTesting key pair: {i}")
        keys = genKeys(p,q)
        printKeys(keys)
        p = keys["priv"]["p"]
        q = keys["priv"]["q"]
        d = keys["priv"]["d"]
        e = keys["pub"]["e"]
        n = keys["pub"]["n"]
        phin = (p - 1)*(q - 1)
        cgcd1,qs = rgcd(phin, e)
        cgcd2,qs = rgcd(phin, n)

        print(f"\n1 < e < phi(n)? {(1 < e) and (e < phin)}")
        print(f"gcd(phi(n),e):{cgcd1}")
        print(f"gcd(phi(n),n):{cgcd2}\n")

        for j in range(1, msgtests+1):
            msg = randint(1, n)

            ciphertext = enc(msg, keys["pub"])
            dmsg = dec(ciphertext, keys["priv"])

            print(f"msg:{msg},ct:{ciphertext},dt:{dmsg}")

            try:
                assert dmsg == msg
                print("success")
                test.succ()
            except AssertionError:
                print("failure")
                test.fail()
```

recursive gcd function:

```
    quotient = str(_a / _b)
    regex = re.search("([\d]*)([.][\d]*)", quotient)
    # print(f"quotient: {regex.group(1)}")
    # print(f"remainder: {regex.group(2)}")
    intquotient = int(regex.group(1))
    remainder = _a % _b
    _quotients.append(intquotient)

    if remainder == 0:
        return _b, _quotients
    else:
        return gcdr(_b, remainder, _quotients)
```

EEA function:

```
    calcedgcd, quotients = gcd(_phin, e)

    t = [0,1]
    i = 2
    # print(f"quotients: {quotients}")

    while len(t) <= len(quotients):
        t_2 = t[i - 2]
        q_1 = quotients[i - 2]
        t_1 = t[i - 1]
        ti = t_2 - q_1*t_1
        t.append(ti)
        i += 1
    
    # print(f"ts: {t}")
    return t[i-1]
```

encryption and decryption functions:

```
def enc(_msg, _key):
    return pow(_msg, _key["e"], _key["n"])

def dec(_msg, _key):
    return pow(_msg, _key["d"], _key["n"])
```

successful output:

```
Testing key pair: 25
p=1061  q=1117  n=1185137       phi(n)=1182960
e=122333        d=537797

1 < e < phi(n)? True
gcd(phi(n),e):1
gcd(phi(n),n):1

msg:1164474,ct:377651,dt:1164474
success
msg:605699,ct:229840,dt:605699
success
msg:1170312,ct:479586,dt:1170312
success
msg:819764,ct:898204,dt:819764
success
msg:651333,ct:110526,dt:651333
success
msg:164817,ct:1157449,dt:164817
success
msg:937813,ct:104340,dt:937813
success
msg:925814,ct:969072,dt:925814
success
msg:83792,ct:293433,dt:83792
success
msg:957966,ct:646060,dt:957966
success
```

failed output:

```
Testing key pair: 22
p=1061  q=1117  n=1185137       phi(n)=1182960
e=513257        d=426247

1 < e < phi(n)? True
gcd(phi(n),e):1
gcd(phi(n),n):1

msg:876007,ct:597782,dt:719344
failure
msg:800755,ct:28117,dt:848945
failure
msg:869264,ct:400473,dt:613585
failure
msg:47275,ct:901207,dt:567863
failure
msg:216676,ct:923747,dt:523416
failure
msg:338455,ct:456405,dt:687793
failure
msg:388325,ct:1145879,dt:529438
failure
msg:159219,ct:100373,dt:484754
failure
msg:83900,ct:733357,dt:1116303
failure
msg:724147,ct:394341,dt:1103623
failure
```

Comment: `513257 * 426247 mod 1182960 = 1182959` your GCD and Ext-GCD should have an error. You may use this one https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: There was an issue with my ext-gcd algo. I don't really know what it was, but implementing the algo from the link fixed it so many thanks.

Comment: The first rule is testing! Never forget extensive testing before use. You can post your answer. I'll upvote. Just comment me back with using @kelalaka. Welcome and have fun.